# setLocationRelativeTo(null) is not centering the frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, frame

I want to position the frame in the center of the screen, but when I typed f.setLocationRelativeTo(null). It is positioning it to the bottom right corner. Is something wrong with the code? If so how can I change it to center the frame?

```
public class Maze {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Maze();
    }

    public Maze(){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("Maze Game");
        //f.add(new board());
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setSize(500, 400);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When you call `setLocationRelativeTo()` with `null` as the argument, you have to call `setSize()` **before** it.  Otherwise, even though your frame may look like a 500x400 window to the rest of the program (and to you!), to the `setLocationRelativeTo()` method it essentially looks like a single dimensionless point (the top left corner of the window)....which is what it will center, causing the window to appear in the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish should look like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Maze();
}

public Maze(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setTitle("Maze Game");
    f.add(new board());
        //Notice I took out your comment over f.add to show the f.pack() method and where
        //your 'setLocationRelativeTo(null); statement should go in terms of it.
    f.setSize(500, 400);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //NOTICE! I changed the above line from (f.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) to (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
        // DO NOT LOOK OVER THAT!
    f.pack();
    f.setLocaitonRelativeTo(null);

}
```

It's all about order, my friend.